# Return back all messages that contain specific users in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

So I have a message class, and I'm trying to create a GetMethod that returns all the messages exchanged between 2 users via a linq method.

my class:

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int MessageId { get; set; }

    public string MessageContent { get; set; }

    public string Sender { get; set; }

    public string Receiver { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
}
```

So in my method I am trying to grab all messages between users1 and users 2

this what I have so far

```
    [Route("GetConversation")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetConverstion([FromQuery] string user1, string user2 )
    {
        var conversation =  _dbContext.Messages.Where(x => x.Receiver == user1 && x.Sender == user2).SingleOrDefault();

        return Ok(new { conversation });


    }
```

but of course this only returns 1 message, only from user2 to user1.

Can someone advise how I could use LINQ to return all messages between senders and receivers?

here is a snapshot of my db layout for a better visualization:

[image: MyDb]

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can switch the values - `.Where((x => x.Receiver == user1 && x.Sender == user2) || (x => x.Sender == user1 && x.Receiver == user2))` - but I'm wondering why you use `SingleOrDefault` if you want **all** the messages, as that will throw if there is more than one message between the two users? (as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netcore-3.1) say, 'this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be good enough

```
var conversations =  _dbContext.Messages.Where(x => 
                          (x.Receiver == user1 || x.Receiver == user2) && 
                          (x.Sender == user2 || x.Sender == user1))
```

Notice that this will return messages sent from user1 to user1 and from user2 to user2 but this check becomes necessary only if your logic doesn't prevent it.

Another point to consider is the fact that the query could return more than one record so, the call to SingleOrDefault() has been removed.

Comment: argh I'm such a fool, i had something so close to this earlier on and abandoned it due to second guessing myself!  thank you so much this worked like a dream!

Comment: Would this not return a message that `user1` sent to themself?

Comment: @stuartd yes. the solution in your comment is better.

Answer (score 1):

You already have your answer, you just need to add another set of conditions for cases where the receiver is user 2 and sender is user 1. The other reason is that you are calling .SingleOrDefault(), which will necessarily either return a single row or null. Try returning a List instead...

```
var conversation =  _dbContext.Messages.Where(x => (x.Receiver == user1 && x.Sender == user2) || (x.Receiver == user2 && x.Sender == user1)).ToList();
```